# adding data to TableView : javafx

Tags: javafx

I am trying to add data to a tableview created using scene builder but
 when i try to run the program only one column  is displayed in the tableview
 what could i be missing. i have looked into examples available and i can't see  where am going wrong.
Here is my Fxml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="352.0" prefWidth="423.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.TableController">
   <children>
      <TableView fx:id="tableview" layoutX="16.0" layoutY="48.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="392.0">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn fx:id="firstcol" prefWidth="108.0" text="first" />
          <TableColumn fx:id="lastcol" prefWidth="157.0" text="lastame" />
           <TableColumn fx:id="phonecol" prefWidth="130.0" text="phone" />
        </columns>
      </TableView>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

my controller class

```
package application;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;


public class TableController {
    @FXML private   TableView <Person>tableview;
    @FXML private TableColumn<Person,String> firstcol;
    @FXML private  TableColumn <Person,String>lastcol;
    @FXML private  TableColumn <Person,String>phonecol;

    private final ObservableList<Person> data =
            FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                    new Person("Bob", "Smith","77777"),
                    new Person("Bob", "Smith","999"),
                    new Person("george", "Smith","263737")

            );
    @FXML
    protected void initialize() {

        //setting up the columns
        firstcol.setCellValueFactory( new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("first"));
        lastcol.setCellValueFactory( new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("last") );
        phonecol.setCellValueFactory( new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("phone") );

        //setting up the table data source

        tableview.setItems( data );
    }

}
```

my main class

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;



public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Parent root;
        try {
            root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Table.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

my person class

```
package application;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

public class Person {
    private final SimpleStringProperty first;
    private final SimpleStringProperty last;
    private final SimpleStringProperty phone;


    public Person(
            String first,
            String last,
            String phone
    ) {
        this.first = new SimpleStringProperty( first );
        this.last = new SimpleStringProperty( last );
        this.phone = new SimpleStringProperty( phone );
    }


    public String getFirstName() {
        return first.get();
    }

    public void setFirstName(String first) {
        this.first.set( first );
    }



    public String getLastName() {
        return last.get();
    }

    public void setLastName(String last) {
        this.last.set( last );
    }



    public String getPhone() {
        return phone.get();
    }
    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone.set( phone );
    }
}
```

the phone column is the one that displays

Comment: Please post your `Person` class

Comment: sorry i had omitted the person class, i have edited my question

Comment: Thanks james D, i have followed the other question and it has worked